# mysqlがログイン・起動できない

Tags: mysql

php+laravelからmysqlの操作を勉強していたのですが、mysqlにログインできません。
色々と検索を行い、試行錯誤しているのですが中々解決をしないので質問をさせて頂きました。

#### 試したこと

まずログインを試みた際に以下のように表示されました。

```
ec2-user:~/environment/test $ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

そこからmysqlがインストールされていないのかと考えて調べてみたのですが、存在しているように見えます。

```
ec2-user:~/environment/test $ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.38-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

なのでサーバーを起動させようとしたのですが以下の通り表示されました。
何がいけなかったのでしょうか？

```
ec2-user:~/environment/test $ mysql.server start
bash: mysql.server: command not found
```

Comment: 実行環境に関する情報 (OS の種類やバージョン等) を追記してください。mysql のバージョンで検索してみると AWS Cloud9 のようにも見えますが、合っていますか？

Comment: はい。合っています！

Answer (score 1):

以下のいずれかを試してみてください。

```bash
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

または

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Comment: mariadbの箇所はDB_DATABASEに書かれているデータベース名を記入するのでしょうか？

Comment: 実行してみました。

Comment: ec2-user:~/environment/test $ sudo systemctl start mysqld
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit not found.と表示されました。